# laravel how to transfer relationshp to an array

Tags: php, mysql, xml, laravel, laravel-4

I have these tables:

`xml_documents` table that has just one column, which is `id`

`master_information` table that has these columns `id`, `xml_document_id`, `container`, `next_page`

the relationship is one to one.

everything is working on my model. I can add, update, delete and every thing is working perfectly.

now I want to export my model as xml.

so I need to transfer my xmlDocument model to an array, then transfer this array to xml. I can do the second part myself, which is transfering php array to xml, but I don't know how to transfer the model to an array.

I tried this:

```
$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::find(4)->get()->toArray();
dd($xmlDocument)
```

but I got all the xml_document rows like this

`array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(4) } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(5) } }`

Then I tried this:

```
 $xmlDocument = XmlDocument::find(4)->toArray();
    dd($xmlDocument)
```

but I got this:

```
array(1) { ["id"]=> int(5) }
```

I need to also get the relationship. for example:

```
 Array (
    [id] = 4
    [xmlInformation] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [container] => 'bla'
            [next_page] => 'bla bla'    
        )
```

can you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

For a specific XmlDocument;

```
XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', <... comma separated list of other relationships>)->find(4)->toArray();
```

For all XmlDocuments;

```
XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', <... comma separated list of other relationships>)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: maybe you mean `XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation')->find(4)->toArray();` right?

Comment: That one just was not sure what it was called.

Comment: that gives me this: `array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["master_information"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["xml_document_id"]=> int(4) ["container"]=> string(9) "container" ["next_page"]=> string(9) "next page" } }` so I guess the first part is solved. however how can I specify more models please? for example `->with('MasterInformation', 'DetailsInformation')` **?**

Comment: Oh i get what you mean if you have them as a relationship just add them into the with. :)

Comment: +1 to you bty, but not that what I mean. I mean the `xml_document` table has another relationship with `details_attribute` table. what you gave me is the relationship between `xml_document` and `master_information` so how can I get the relationshiop between `xml_document` and **both of** `master_information` and `details_information`

Comment: it seems you just updated the question again :) let me test it

Comment: I did this `$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', `GeneralInformation`)->find(4)->toArray();` but I got exception : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::()`

Comment: Each of the relationship name need to be in quotes '<name of relationship>', '<name of relationship>' within the with().

Comment: I don't want to be rude but please just the last thing, I did this `$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', 'GeneralInformation', 'DetailsAttributes')->find(4)->toArray();` and it works perfectly. the last thing is that the `MasterInformation` also has a one to many relationship with a `MasterAttributes`, how can I add it to the code I showed you please? just this thing :)

Comment: $xmlDocument = XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', 'MasterInformation.MasterAttributes', 'GeneralInformation', 'DetailsAttributes')->find(4)->toArray();

Comment: WOW WOW WOW thaaaaaaaaaanks. I wish I could upvote to you 100 times. many thanks dear